# How to use this inequality to prove the $\left(1+{1\over n}\right)^n<\left(1+{1\over n+1}\right)^{n+1}$?

Tags: inequality

This is an exercise on my text book, given that

if $k>1$,  $${n(n-1)\dots(n-k+1)\over k!} \left({1\over n}\right)^k<{(n+1)n\dots (n-k+2)\over k!} \left({1\over n+1}\right)^k$$

My problem is how to use this inequality to prove that

if $n\geq1$, 
$$\left(1+{1\over n}\right)^n<\left(1+{1\over n+1}\right)^{n+1}$$

Answer (score 3):

HINT: Use the binomial theorem to expand both sides of the desired inequality. For example,

$$\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}k\left(\frac1n\right)^k\;.$$

Note that

$$\binom{n}k=\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)\ldots(n-k+1)}{k!}\;.$$

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
\left(1 + {1 \over n}\right)^{n}
&=
\sum_{\ell = 0}^{n}{n \choose \ell}{1 \over n^{\ell}}
=
\sum_{\ell = 0}^{n}
{n\left(n - 1\right)\ldots\left(n - \ell + 1\right) \over \ell!}\,
{1 \over n^{\ell}}
\\[3mm]&<
\sum_{\ell = 0}^{n}
{\left(n + 1\right)n\ldots\left(n - \ell + 2\right) \over \ell!}\,
{1 \over \left(n + 1\right)^{\ell}}
=
\sum_{\ell = 0}^{n}{n + 1 \choose \ell}\,{1 \over \left(n + 1\right)^{\ell}}
\tag1
\\[3mm]&<
\sum_{\ell = 0}^{n + 1}{n + 1 \choose \ell}\,{1 \over \left(n + 1\right)^{\ell}}
=
\left(1 + {1 \over n + 1}\right)^{n + 1}
\end{align}

$$
\begin{array}{|c|}\hline\\
\color{#ff0000}{\large\quad%
\left(1 + {1 \over n}\right)^{n}
\color{#000000}{\large\ <\ }
\left(1 + {1 \over n + 1}\right)^{n + 1}
\quad}
\\ \\ \hline
\end{array}
$$

In $\left(1\right)$, I used your textbook information.